# How can I combine multiple tables that have matching columns, but keep all rows?

Tags: sql, join, union-all

Working on my case study, I have 12 tables with 13 matching columns (ride_id, rideable_type, station_name, etc). I want to combine these into one table so all my data is in one place. I do NOT want to combine values, as there are repeat values that need to stay separate.

I've tried two solutions so far:

```
2022_divvy_trip_data AS
(
SELECT * FROM case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202201_divvy_tripdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 'case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202202_divvy_tripdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 'case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202203_divvy_tripdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 'case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202204_divvy_tripdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202205_divvy_tripdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 'case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202206_divvy_tripdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202207_divvy_tripdata'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202208_divvy_tripdata'
)t
```

This always produced some kind of error, like "Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:5]". I also tried "CREATE TABLE 2022_divvy_trip_data" but this never worked either.

Then I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM 'case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202301_divvy_tripdata'
FULL JOIN case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_-rider_data.202202_divvy-tripdata
USING (ride_id)
FULL JOIN case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202203_divvy_tripdata
USING (ride_id)
FULL JOIN case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202204_divvy_tripdata'
USING (ride_id)
FULL JOIN case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202205_divvy_tripdata
USING (ride_id)
FULL JOIN 'case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202206_divvy_tripdata'
USING (ride id)
FULL JOIN 'case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202207_divvy_tripdata'
USING (ride_id)
FULL JOIN "case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202208_divvy-tripdata'
USING (ride_id)
FULL JOIN case-study-cyclist-379323.cyclistic_rider_data.202209_divvy_tripdata
USING (ride_id)
```

And that did complete, but it saved each column individually. Instead of one column named ride_id, I have 12 named ride_id_1, ride_id_2, and so on.

Comment: You shouldn't need to alias after your UNION ALL create statement. I would think `create table my_new_table as (query 1 union all query 2 union all ... etc);` would work as long as you have the same columns and column types. Did you try removing the 't' alias?

Comment: @Isolated Yes, I got "Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT but got ")" at [11:1]" Which is my ')'.  Full code is now `CREATE TABLE trip_test AS (SELECT * FROM table_a UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_b UNION ALL) ;`

Comment: You have a UNION ALL after your last select statement. Remove that. Should look like this: `create table my_new_table as (select * from table1 union all select * from table2);` Also, which dbms?

Comment: Oh my god, I could cry. That did it, I initially got an error about assigning a data set, but once I added that it worked. I should've asked three hours ago. Thank you so much for your help! If anyone else comes along after this, I was using BigQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct CTAS statement that should work for most DBMS...

```
create table my_new_table as (
 select * from table1 union all 
 select * from table2 union all
 .
 .
 select * from table11 union all
 select * from table12
 );
```

No need for alias. Also, it will fail if your tables have different number of columns. You may need to pad columns within each select statement if you have a different number columns.